# Store data of people who clicked on a button on Facebook

Tags: facebook, button, store

I would really appreciate some help with the Facebook application I currently work on. 
I developing a simple Facebook application, and I need to store the data of the people, who click the "I want to win button". I'm not sure if I should use plain, old vanilla PHP, or if the Facebook API provides some simple way to do that, so I would be really glad for some ideas about this.

I read about the topic, but I can't really "see the Matrix" yet, so every answer is appriciated. Also I'm more interested in ideas and not the implementation, as I'm fairly confident in my programming skills.

Thank you everybody!

Richard

Comment: is this a canvas application? are you asking for even basic permissions?

Comment: It is a canvas application, altough it is cretaed in Wordpress trough the Facebook Tabs Manager plugin. I suspected that I will have to ask permissions but as it is only a static page now, I haven't done that yet.

Comment: ok what sort of data of the user do you want?

Comment: It would be enough to store something that identifies them uniqly, so I think it would be enough to store there Facebook ID (maybe their name for convenience but it is not necessary).

One of the main thing I am not sure of  if I have to use an external database (for example the one in Wordpress) or if there are some native Facebook API ways to collect name (for example a special kind of list, or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need to use an external db, coz facebook will not store the data for you. However facebook does store the **connection** that a user makes with the app, i.e. when a user gives some(even basic) permissions to your app. Hence when an old user comes to your app you can know which, and if it is an old user.

Facebook sends your entry script a [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), which contains data about the user visiting your app, this request will have a `user_id` field **only if** the user has made the [connection/authorized](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth) your app, hence you know if it's an old user or new.

Once you have the `user_id` you can call the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to get info about the user. In the [php SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) you can easily call `$facebookObject->api('/me','GET');` to get user info.

You can easily call the functions anytime, so if you want to make a call when a user clicks your button, you can do that.

Check out the links i have included, *thoroughly*, you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is clear a lot of things I was confused about. It is really appreciated.